# How to highlight the area with maximum number of changes in a time series plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I am trying to play with some time series data. I would like to plot the area with maximum numbers of changes based on some interval.

I have written some sample code but I am not able to move forward in highlighting the region.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns


f = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(300, 1)))
sns.tsplot(f[0])
```

[image]

I want to highlight the region with maximum changes say with window size 30.

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum number of changes"? Certainly in the random sequence, each point is a change from the previous point, so each region has the same number of changes.

Comment: Say for a  window of size 30. If I move this window horizontally without any overlap, the number of changes is greater than 20, I want highlight the region

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach that performs most of the operations in numpy, and then displays the region with [matplotlib.axvspan](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan.htmln):

```
f = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50,size=(300, 1))) # dataframe
y = f[0].values      # working vector in numpy

thr = 5 # criterion for counting as a change
chunk_size = 30 # window length
chunks = np.array_split(y, y.shape[0]/chunk_size) # split into 30-element chunks    
# compute how many elements differ from one element to the next
diffs_by_chunk = [(np.abs(np.ediff1d(chunk)) > thr).sum() for chunk in chunks]
ix = np.argmax(diffs_by_chunk) # chunk with most differences

sns.tsplot(f[0])
plt.axvspan(ix * chunk_size, (ix+1) * chunk_size, alpha=0.5)
```

[image: highlight changes]

With a baseline of uniform random data, it is difficult to relate this to a use case, but alternative criteria for what to maximise over might be useful, e.g. just looking at the sum of absolute changes, rather than the number that exceed a threshold:

```
diffs_by_chunk = [(np.abs(np.ediff1d(chunk))).sum() for chunk in chunks] # criterion #2
```

It would also be possible to show multiple regions that all have enough differences:

```
for i, df in enumerate(diffs_by_chunk):
    if df >= 25:
        sns.mpl.pyplot.axvspan(i*chunk_size, (i+1)*chunk_size, alpha=0.5)
```